# upload maven project file on save to google app engine like netbeans

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I am new to eclipse and spring maven projects, I want to auto upload files whenever changes are  made to it. I am using google app engine, I want to upload files on google app engine, like in netbeans, it sync file with server whenever changes are made.
Please Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The new [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse) doesn't support this directly.  And to be honest, it's not an approach I'd recommend: it's better to launch and debug it locally (*Debug As > App Engine Standard*) and then use *Deploy* to deploy your working version.

That said, providing you use an external build tool like Maven, you could add your own *builder* to build and deploy your war on each build.  To do so:

1. Right-click on your project and select *Properties*
2. Navigate to the *Builders* tab.
3. Select *New…* and select the *Program* configuration type
4. In the *Edit Configuration* dialog:

   - the *Location* is the path to your program (`mvn`)
   - the *Working Directory* would be the location of your project; use the *Browse Workspace…* button to select your project
   - the *Arguments* will be `package appengine:deploy`
5. Then switch to the *Build Options* tab and you'll like wan to add *During auto builds* too, to cause the action to happen on save.

All of this assumes your `pom.xml` is properly configured.  See the [Maven and App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven) page for details.  You could use Gradle too with the same approach.